# How to update the font of the screen in different ways?

Tags: python, fonts, pygame, screen

Below you see some modified code from another user here on Stack Overflow.
It contains the same text on the left side and on the right side. It also updates the 2 fonts on the screen every 2 second. Now, is it possible to split the screen into 2 halves? That means, on the left side the font `text5` updates dynamically. Every 2 second the font gets replaced.

On the right side of the screen, I want the font `text4`to update, but not get replaced. That means, the font overlaps.

How to solve this problem?

```
import pygame
import time

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    done = False

    font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 72)


    start = time.time()
    i=0
    F = 0;








        text4 = None
        text5 = None
        while not done:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    done = True
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    done = True

                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                        F = F + 1
                        text4 = font.render(str(F), True, (128, 128, 0))
                        text5 = font.render(str(F), True, (0, 128, 0))


            passed_time = time.time() - start
            if passed_time > 2 and i < 5:  
                start = time.time()  
                i += 1

            screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

            if text4 != None:
                screen.blit(text4,(460 - text4.get_width() // 1, 40 + i * 20 - text4.get_height() // 2))
                screen.blit(text5,(260 - text5.get_width() // 1, 40 + i * 20 - text5.get_height() // 2))

            # [...]

            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: *"On the right side of the screen, I want the font to update, but not get replaced."* I've no idea what you mean. There is only 1 text (a single number) at all.

Comment: My bad, I just updated the code. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just draw the text in a loop for the positions in range [0, i]:

```py
for j in range(i+1):
    screen.blit(text4,(460 - text4.get_width() // 1, 40 + j * 20 - text4.get_height() // 2))
```

e.g.:

```py
text4, text5 = None, None
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        # [...]

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                F = F + 1
                text4 = font.render(str(F), True, (128, 128, 0))
                text5 = font.render(str(F), True, (0, 128, 0))

    # [...]

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    if text4 != None:
        for j in range(i+1):
            screen.blit(text4,(460 - text4.get_width() // 1, 40 + j * 20 - text4.get_height() // 2))
    if text5 != None:
        screen.blit(text5,(260 - text5.get_width() // 1, 40 + i * 20 - text5.get_height() // 2))

    # [...]
```

Comment: I don't really understand it. Could you explain the role of the loop? Do you keep the line `screen.fill((255, 255, 255))` or you delete it?

Comment: @DerickKolln *"I want the font text4to update, but not get replaced. That means, the font overlaps."* - Since the screen is cleared  in every frame (`screen.fill((255, 255, 255))`), `text4` has to be drawn multiple times per frame, dependent on the value of `i`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a solution to avoid the condition? Maybe use to fill only half screen?

Comment: @DerickKolln Which condition do you want to avoid?

Comment: I postet the comment in the wrong section. It belongs to the other question i asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56511380/how-to-update-the-font-of-the-screen-in-different-ways/56513315#56513315    But the problem is solved already. I avoided the condition by filling only parts of the screeen